# Write recursive sub-functions and non-recursive sub-functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm newbie to Matlab
I have an assignment :
Legendre polynomial Pn(x), n=0,1,2,. . . The recursive formula of is
[image]

Write recursive sub-functions and non-recursive sub-functions separately to find the value of the Legendre polynomial function

This is my code :

```
function P =Legendre(n,x)
syms x;
n = input('n=');
    if n==0
        P=1;
    elseif n==1
        P=x;
    elseif n>=2
        P=((2*n-1)/n)*x*Legendre(n-1)-((n-1)/n)*Legendre(n-2);
    end 
end
```

But I get an error message:

```
Unrecognized function or variable 'Legendre'.

Error in ti4 (line 9)
        P=((2*n-1)/n)*x*Legendre(n-1)-((n-1)/n)*Legendre(n-2);
```

Sorry for the stupid question. Can anyone help me? Thank u so much

Comment: Is this code in a file named `Legendre.m`?

Comment: Why are you using `syms`? And asking for user input?

Comment: @Pursuit File named ti4.m

Comment: I want to assign x as hidden, out the hidden equation x

Comment: So the direct answer is that the function needs to be in a file named `FUNCTIONNAME.m`. Matlab recognizes this function as `ti4`.  For almost every use of this function that I have ever needed, I would remove the first two lines completely. ... OK, needs a whole answer. Stand by

Comment: Besides what Pursuit told you in the answer below, you need to do `Legendre(n-1, x)` when you recursively call the function.

Answer (score 1):

A few things are probably going on here.

**File name needs to match function name** (for the primary function)

In your case, the filename needs to be `Legendre.m`.

**Symbolic toolbox OR do you want an answer**

for most uses of this function, I would leave two full inputs, just as you have them. Bur I would remove the first two lines completely.

As it is, the first two lines will break your inputs. The value for `n` is reset by the `input` function. I'm actually not sure what happens when you declare an existing variable `x`, to a `sym`.

**Input consistency**

You are setting up a function with two inputs, named `n` and `x`. But when you maek your recursive calls you only pass in one variable. The easiest thing to do here is simply keep passing `n` in as the first input.

(Right now, you are trying to pass in `x` in the recursive calls, but it will be interpreted as `n`.)